# pass data to database with javascript in asp.net mvc4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

```
<ul>
@foreach (var item in Model.Users.Where(s => s.DepartmentId == 3))
{
<li>
     @item.UserName
</li> 
}
</ul>
```

I have usernames with this code **"item.UserName"** from database.

If i click any username , ı want to keep it's selected value on **SESSION**.

Than

If a click to button, it must send user name's selected value and send to database with javascript.

Session must be because i will make many processes like this that is why i did not write all codes.

Answer (score 0):

Another way you could do this would be to add the names to a hidden array when they are clicked. Then, when you POST, the names will go to the database. You don't need a session for this. Easier than maintaining a session object.

Comment: do you have any example for it ?

Comment: This is how you declare the element: $("input[type='hidden'][name='name[]']").val('Sonor'); This is how you add values on the click event: var arr = new Array();
arr.push('value1');
arr.push('value2');